# Comparing classifiers with a fixed dataset split across multiple runs with same parameters

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistical-significance, t-test

Let us say we have 4 different sets of non-linear neural net classifier parameters that we can denote A,B,C,D. The weights are all randomly initialized at the beginning of training.

Each classifier is trained on the *exact same train-test split* and after each run we collect some metrics on our test set. One of these metrics could be the overall classification accuracy on the test set. I have found many answers using some form of cross-validation or random splitting of the dataset, but here it is fixed.

Since each classifier is using the exact same data split, I assume we can only measure the impact of the change in parameters along with the inherent randomness of the training process.

Now if I do multiple training runs using the same parameters we might get a table of results like this:

| Model | Accuracy |
| --- | --- |
| A_1 | 83% |
| A_2 | 86% |
| ... | ... |
| B_39 | 83% |
| B_40 | 85% |
| ... | ... |
| D_22 | 86% |
| D_23 | 82% |
| ... | ... |

***What would be an appropriate statistical test of detecting a difference in mean between all or pairs of the models?***

Initially I thought a t-test would be sufficient since the accuracy scores seem to be normally distributed around some mean value, but what I got stuck on was whether we have independence between the models. Since each model is trained from scratch the linking dependency is the same underlying data split and all the parameters they have in common, but it is not clear what would be the correct pairing if I were to use a paired t-test.

Comment: All trainings use the same splitted dataset, but have different initializations. So we could call your setting partially paired.